# Columns Overlapping on Reference column

Tags: spacing, formatting, cross-referencing, columns

First off would just like to say I am pretty new at using latex, my supervisor wants me to use it to publish a paper. I feel like the beginner of beginners when it comes to LaTeX. So if this is painfully obvious to anyone here I am sorry.

The issue is that within my references section, the columns overlap with the main text column and some of the other references too. I have researched this a little but when trying to fix these errors, nothing worked, again being a novice i could have easily missed this. I attached the code for the beginning section to see if this is not enough and you need more information just say and I will reply with the code needed. I also attached an image which shows what the issue looks like

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the 
% first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.

\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.7}


%\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
```

[image: Referencing issue image example]

---

UPDATE

Attatched is the entries for O'Donnell and Cimpanu

[image: Cimpanu Entry]

[image: O'Donnell Entry]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please edit your posting to show the bibtex entries for [12] (Cimpanu) and [13] (O'Donnell). Incidentally, you should make a habit of encasing all instances of `North Korea` in `title` fields in curly braces, to prevent BibTeX from converting them to lowercase.

Comment: What happens if you change `$100` to `\$100` in the Cimpanu entry and perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: @Mico this worked!!!!!! Thank you so much for the help and quick responses, i thought i might be days till this started working. Many thanks again

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by correcting a typo (see comments).